# Error creating shared memory

Tags: delphi

I have to debug an application built using Delphi CodeGear 2009 that was built by someone else than me and this person is not part of the company anymore.

Strange problem, when i load the project into code gear and run the software which should actually work, i get an error :

> First chance exception at $753CB9BC. Exception class Exception with
>   message 'Error creating shared memory
>   Global\{B40FBC0C-FEBD-11DD-B3EA-FC6656D89593} (5)'. Process
>   OrderCenter.exe (836268)

I can't even run the software in step by step mode, it seems to occur before i even get into the ran application itself. I have no idea whatsoever how to fix this error, i sure can look at the code and understand it and maybe modify it but i sure don't understand at all how to fix an error like that **without any documentation on google**. I tried browsing google and SO for a while trying all sorts of keyword combination and nothing comes out of it.

How do I go about debugging this? Where do I start looking?

---

**Edit #1**

To clarify, I'm getting an exception before even entering into the application and it is not even debuggable.  I'll gladly paste a stack trace ASAP so that everyone can see where it is crashing.  Apologies for not having thought of this initially.

I have searched for the exact error message on Google, but I haven't found anything near useful.  Here's a couple examples:

http://www.google.ca/#hl=fr&output=search&sclient=psy-ab&q=Error+creating+shared+memory&oq=Error+creating+shared+memory

http://www.google.ca/#hl=fr&sclient=psy-ab&q=delphi+Error+creating+shared+memory&oq=delphi+Error+creating+shared+memory

---

**Edit #2**

Thank you for the person that took the time to specify there was some kind of initialization procedure, i searched in all files and found that procedure and found that the code is crashing here:

```
if not AlreadyRunning(ProcessName, TFormMain, False, False, True) then
```

If, i try to look at the declaration of this code, it seems it's indeed trying to create a global shared memory object probably some kind of Mutex to prevent double initialization.

My first guess is i can probably just ditch this part of code without any direct consequence apart from the fact that the user will now be able to run 2+ same applications.

**On a side note,** I wonder why this would fail in the first place (Win7, admin account)?

*PS:* The reason i wasn't able to find where the error occured at first was because the application was in Release mode and not in debug mode, it took me some time and deep UI search to notice it under the Build configurations in the file manager. Nothing else indicated me i was in release mode until i tried putting breakpoints in the initialization portion of the app and it wouldn't stop...

Answer (score 0, accepted):

**I posted this answer because the edits to the question make it hard to understand the history.   Hat tip to David for understanding the meaning of an exception message without seeing the code, and explaining that to the new guy on the block, the OP.**

It seems that with help from David, you have located some code that prevents duplicate instances of the code from running. If you remove it, you will likely not incur other penalties, but since we can't read your code we can't tell you that for sure.  Also I will note that the concept of release and debug modes are blindingly obvious to native developers (C++ and Delphi) and perhaps more of a subtlety to those not familiar with compilers and native code.  It might be worth getting a book on Delphi if you're going to maintain a Delphi application.  There are more dragons out there and the waters get deep very fast if this is your first compiled/native language.

Most likely this code which is dying is an element that was either:

(a) Copied and pasted from some cookbook of common delphi techniques, or

(b) Part of a component or class that was not even written by the original author

This code may have bugs induced by moving this component code written for, for example, Delphi 5, in 1998, on Windows NT,  so that it no longer functions in Delphi XE3, on WIndows 7 or 8.
This phenomenon is not unique to delphi and is called "bit rot".  In other words, the environment is a bit of a moving target, and old code often breaks like this. Fixing this without knowledge of Delphi, or the Win32 APIs involved, by a PHP programmer, would be like having a car mechanic do surgery on my liver. I wouldn't give the guy odds.

Nevertheless here's a plan:

A. Comment it out.

B. Continue testing!

Hey sorry about sniping at ya, now we're even! ;-)

Comment: No problem, actually, i think the reason i hate so much this application is due to the fact that no here at work codes Delphi anymore, that i'm stuck trying to understand an IDE that i'm not used to, mixed with the urgency feeling, the no documentation at all, boss in vacation for paternity leave... that makes a lot to deal with all at once...

Comment: Hire a contractor.  (Nudge nudge, wink wink.)

Comment: I commented out several portions of the application that seem to make the application bug out, i have mysql connections refering to inexistent servers and database anymore, code that stops working while it was before, etc... bla bla bla, nice week!

Comment: Am not entitled to take this decision ... yet!

Comment: Anyways, general advice:  If it's a different overall question than the original one (crash at startup) ask a NEW specific question AFTER doing some research and debug single-stepping around. :-)

Comment: You accepted this answer?! Really? Even though your latest edit appears to confirm what I wrote? That seems a little mean.

Comment: @DavidHeffernan Both anwsers are perfectly valid, you have 12 upvotes he has 1 from me... whats the issue here? You want more points? I'm not continuing this useless discussion

Comment: Well, you could at least acknowledge that I got it right. Have a look at the comments you left on my answer. Ask Warren which answer he thinks you should accept.

Comment: I believe that Mathieu figured it out after David figured it out for him! :-) +1 David.  I believe 13 upvotes is lucky, isn't it?

Comment: Anyway, when you say "I would now need expert advice as to why this function can fail", I suspect that I gave you the answer to that already. It's because the object is in the global namespace. If it's created in a different session then you won't be able to access it unless it's been properly secured.

Comment: I have recently seen code that does not properly handle these security descriptors that used to work in Windows (even though it shouldn't ever have have worked) and no longer works in Windows, even Windows XP, once it is patched to a recent level. I suspect that the broken shared memory code I have seen worked only before Microsoft engineers started fixing glaring bugs in the Windows APIs, some of which were probably responsible for some nasty exploits. I think this question should be left done, and he should ask a new question, as the repeated edits and shifting focus are a bad thing.

Comment: And @WarrenP, you know not to take any offence from me I trust

Answer (score 15):

The error is raised specifically by your program. That can be discerned from this message:

> Exception class Exception with message 'Error creating shared memory Global\{B40FBC0C-FEBD-11DD-B3EA-FC6656D89593} (5)

That has all the hallmarks of an exception raised by a Delphi program. The hexadecimal is indicated by `$` rather than `0x`, and the first words of the message are standard Delphi. I'm going to assume that it is your program that raises this exception.

First of all, the exception class is `Exception`. To the very best of my knowledge, nothing in the RTL, or any reputable third party libraries raises an exception of class `Exception`. That is considered bad practice. Always raise a sub-class of `Exception`. Ergo, your application's code is raising this exception.

Secondly, the message describes an error in creating shared memory, and gives a named object in the `Global` namespace. This is probably a named file mapping object.

And finally the message includes a Win32 error code retrieved by a call to `GetLastError`. That code is number 5, our old friend [`ERROR_ACCESS_DENIED`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-gb/library/windows/desktop/ms681382.aspx#ERROR_ACCESS_DENIED).

So it would seem that this program operates in tandem with a separate process and communication is effected using shared memory, a file mapping. And the security for that file mapping has not been set correctly for whatever reason.

The object has been placed in the `Global` namespace, which is what you do if you need it to be shared between sessions. So it seems plausible that the other process resides in a service in session 0. Perhaps the security attributes that are needed to secure an object for cross-session access have not been correctly specified.

The code that raises the exception will look a little like this:

```
FileMapping := OpenFileMapping(FILE_MAP_READ or FILE_MAP_WRITE, 
  False, PChar(FileMappingName));
if FileMapping=0 then
  raise Exception.CreateFormat(
    'Error creating shared memory %s (%d)',
    [FileMappingName, GetLastError]
  );
```

That's about all I can say from the evidence presented. But now you know what to search for in your program in order to locate the code which is failing. Over to you.

Comment: I've voted to re-open, based on the quality and usefulness of the answer.  This may be a good opportunity for one of those "reversal" medals, if the OP would care to improve the question....

Comment: A person who cannot even locate where an exception is raised in Delphi is asking far too narrowly defined a question to be useful here.  Help my foot is hurting, please help me figure out what calibre of bullet has put a hole in my shoe, please. Kthxbye.

Comment: Thanks for the investigation and yes i do know how to check for errors in code or locate exceptions but the problem is the stack leads only to external code libraries such as the kernel. Like i said in my post, i don't even get into the application even if i start it in step by step mode.

Comment: You need to start off with a search for the text if the exception that your program is raising.

Comment: @DavidHeffernan "I tried browsing google and SO for a while trying all sorts of keyword combination and nothing comes out of it." isn't that enough to tell you i tried all possible search combination INCLUDING the exact error message?

Comment: You won't find that text on Google, or at SO. What I am telling you is that that text comes from your program. It can be found in the source code for `OrderCenter.exe`.

Comment: I don't understand your question edit. I think you need to re-read my answer. The code that raises the exception is part of your program. There's no point searching anywhere other than your own source code.

Comment: David, could you please edit the question so that it asks a question that fits whatever it is you answered? (Right now, it doesn't ask anything at all.) The best I can come up with is "How do I interpret this error message my program prints?" and it still feels too localized.

Comment: David, a fat plus from me. Your answer just shows that good programming skills are just that and not language specific. One can "master" 10 languages but is still a bad programmer. This error is really windows API specific and thus has basically nothing to do with Delphi itself. It would be the same path to debug it in any language actually.

Comment: If you're a PHP programmer, then Windows and such are just parts of the web-browser platform, and are mysterious and unfathomable. Better google it. :-)